# Rotating an L shape of 3 points so that it always faces a certain way.

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

I have 3 points in 2d space that roughly make an L shape. I want the L shape to face a certain way. I'm having trouble coming up with the logic to figure out which angle I should rotate my shape.

Here are the 3 main orientations I encounter and their slight variations;

[Orientations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kpeG5.png)

I want my L to always be like 1-A (top left).

I know which point is the corner point. What I do is I get the angle to the two other points.

In the case of 1-B these might be (-2, -94) and in 1-C (3, -88). So, for 1-B I'd need to rotate the whole shape by -2 degrees. For 1-C I'd need to rotate by 3 degrees.

In the case of 2-B, my angles are something like (-87, -177) and for 2-C they are (-91, 178). For 2-B, I'd need to rotate the shape by -87 degrees. For 2-C I'd need to rotate by -91 degrees.

I've tried calculating the smaller angle by magnitude and rotating the shape by that.

```
var smaller_angle;

if(math.abs(angle1) < math.abs(angle2))
   smaller_angle = angle1;
else
   smaller_angle = angle2;

shape.rotate(smaller_angle);
```

This works for the majority of the time but it won't work, for example, the shape is similar to 3-A with the angles (0, 88). The above logic rotates by 0 and it fails.

What should my logic be so I can find the angle I'm supposed to rotate this shape, given that I know the corner point and I know the angle between corner and other points?

Comment: what you want is that the bisecting ray is always at $-45 ^{\circ}$ , isn't it ?

Comment: @GCab yes, that sounds correct. I'll look into how I can achieve that.

Comment: just taking the average of the angles ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that your angles are between $-180^\circ$ and $+180^\circ$. The difference between your two angles is about $90^\circ$. If you want to rotate such that one side is along the positive $x$ axis, and the other one towards the negative $y$ axis, all you need to do is rotate by the opposite of the larger angle.
So $$(-2, -94)\to 2\to(0,-92)\\(3, -88)\to -3\to(0, -91)$$Then $$(0,88)\to -88\to (-88,0)$$

Note that this is valid if the negative $x$ axis is not in the region between the legs.

- **How to check for that?** look at the angle difference between the larger and smaller If it is smaller than $180^\circ$ your inner region does not overlap the $-x$ axis, so you are fine. If it is greater that $180^\circ$ you are overlapping.
- **What do you do if you overlap the $-x$ axis?** In that case subtract $360^\circ$ from the larger value. The previous smaller value is now larger, and continue as before

**Note** since the question uses a reference frame upside down (positive x to the right, positive y down), the following is a possible python implementation

```
def rotate(a1,a2):
    sm, la = a1, a2
    if sm>la:
        sm, la = la, sm
    if la-sm>180:
        sm, la = la, sm+360
    return -sm
```

Comment: Imagine the case of 2-B in the picture I posted. My angles could be (-85, 176), in that case I'd need to rotate by 85, not -176. Or am I misunderstanding you?

Comment: And in the case of 3-A, when my angles are (0,88), I'd need to rotate by 88 and not -88.

Comment: When you rotate with a positive angle, you go counterclockwise. So if you rotate 3A by 88, one leg will point up, the other one to the left. I thought you want one right, one down.

Comment: I need to add an extra check when the -x axis is inside the angle between the sides. I will modify my answer soon.

Comment: Understood, thanks. But not sure if because I'm dealing with screen coordinates, when I rotate with a positive angle the shape rotates clockwise. Shouldn't be a big deal at the end though.

Comment: Where is the origin of the coordinate system for the screen? Upper left? Then x axis is horizontal to the right, and y is pointing down. The positive angles are measured from the x axis, in the direction of y axis. So 1B would be (2, 94) not (-2, -94). Then you need to modify my answer to rotate by the opposite of the smaller angle.

Comment: You were right, turns out I made a mistake using the atan2() function. 1B really is (2,94). And yes, origin is the upper left corner. I'll now try your answer with the fixed code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115654/discussion-between-andrei-and-canberk).